# What is a decent word for "spitting"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I want my friend to step aside from wash basin so that I can spit after brushing. What is a decent word for spitting? Is there a better statement to ask him to step aside?

Comment: *Spit* is a decent word, nothing wrong with it. (Yes, in some cultures, the native idea of 'spitting' has seriously negative connotations, but that's not about the English word *per se.* )

Comment: You could be more specific by saying "spit out," instead.

Comment: I can't help wondering how you ask your friend (politely or otherwise) to move aside, while your mouth is full of toothpaste.

Comment: If you have a mouthful of stuff to spit, you can't talk anyway. Shove him or her aside and spit.

Comment: usually "mmm!  mmm!" and pointing to your mouth gets the point across! :-)  Seriously, if you can utter words with your mouth full of toothpaste, "excuse me a second" should work, no need to mention spitting - your roommate should get the context of your request.

Comment: What Kristina says, or "I need to spit,"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it's kind of a mouthful to say, but the clinical term is [*expectorate*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expectorate) (definition from Merriam-Webster).

Comment: That is an interesting term, but a bit unusual when brushing your teeth, I think :).

Comment: To *expectorate* is not from the 'mouth' of spittle, but from the 'throat/ lungs,' esp., of phlegm or congestion.

Comment: Thanks John. The word made my friend step aside instantly. He asked the meaning later:)

Comment: @Kris: Check the definition. Yes, the first sense listed is as you say, but the second one is *spit*. Also, see the definition for [*spit*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spit). It uses *expectorate* right in the definition. I'm not *just* talking from dictionary lookups. I've seen and heard the word used, and it is very often (in my experience, more than half the time) used to mean, precisely, *spit*.

Comment: John, see the OP's friend's reaction which tells all. Avoid that horror-of-horrors. Good Luck.

Comment: The trick is to say the word without spitting.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use the more neutral expression '**to rinse one's mouth**'.

- Please step aside, I need to rinse my mouth!

To rinse:

> - To wash lightly with water.

It may be common practice, but  [rinsing your mouth](http://lifehacker.com/5978107/dont-rinse-your-mouth-out-after-brushing-your-teeth) after brushing your teeth isn't a good idea.

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Rinse